# Emulator stops responding, tables not created

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The application starts and database is created. But the application stops responding when table is to be created. Error message:
table Magazine has no column named KEY_M_NAME. Here is the code for my Helper:

```
import com.example.projectdbms.model.Magazine;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    // LogCat tag
    private static final String LOG = "Helper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Magazine Publishers Db";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_MAGAZINE = "Magazine";
    private static final String TABLE_ARTICLE = "Article";
    private static final String TABLE_EDITOR = "Editor";
    private static final String TABLE_AUTHOR = "Author";
    private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "Category";
    private static final String TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR = "Distributor";
    private static final String TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT = "Advertisement";

    // Common column names


    //Distributor Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_D_NO = "D_no";
    private static final String KEY_DNAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_CITY = "City";
    private static final String KEY_SALES = "Sales";

    //Author Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_A_ID = "A_id";
    private static final String KEY_A_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_A_DOB = "D.O.B.";
    private static final String KEY_A_SEX = "Sex";
    private static final String KEY_A_ARTICLES = "No of articles";

    //Editor Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_E_ID = "E_id";
    private static final String KEY_E_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_E_DOB = "D.O.B.";
    private static final String KEY_E_SEX = "Sex";
    private static final String KEY_E_ARTICLES = "No of articles";

    //Article Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_AR_NO = "Ar_id";
    private static final String KEY_AR_DATE = "Date";
    private static final String KEY_AR_TITLE = "Title";

    //Magazine Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_M_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_EDITION = "Edition";
    private static final String KEY_M_DATE = "Date";
    private static final String KEY_PAGES = "Pages";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "Price";

    //Advertisement Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_PNAME = "Product/Service";
    private static final String KEY_BRAND = "Brand";
    private static final String KEY_SIZE = "Size";

    //Category Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_CNAME = "Category";
    private static final String KEY_C_ARTICLES = "No of articles";

    //Table Create Statements

    //Magazine table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MAGAZINE = "CREATE TABLE " 
    + TABLE_MAGAZINE + "(" + KEY_M_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_EDITION 
    + " INTEGER, " + KEY_M_DATE + " INTEGER," + KEY_PAGES + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " 
    + KEY_PRICE + " REAL, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_M_NAME, KEY_M_DATE))";

    //Editor table      
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EDITOR = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_EDITOR + "(" + KEY_E_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_E_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
    + KEY_E_DOB + " INTEGER, " + KEY_E_SEX + " TEXT," + KEY_E_ARTICLES 
    + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_E_ID))";

    //Author table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_AUTHOR = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_AUTHOR + "(" + KEY_A_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_A_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
    + KEY_A_DOB + " INTEGER, " + KEY_A_SEX + " TEXT," + KEY_A_ARTICLES
    + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_A_ID))";   

    //Articles table 
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_ARTICLE + "(" + KEY_AR_NO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_AR_DATE
    + " INTEGER," + KEY_AR_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_A_ID + " INTEGER, " 
    + KEY_E_ID + "INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_AR_NO)" 
    + "FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES AUTHOR(A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE," + 
    "FOREIGN KEY (E_ID) REFERENCES EDITOR(E_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)";

    //Category table                             
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_CATEGORY + "(" + KEY_CNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_C_ARTICLES
    + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_CNAME))";  

    //Advertisement table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT = "CREATE TABLE " 
    + TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT + "(" + KEY_PNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_BRAND 
    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SIZE + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_PNAME,KEY_BRAND))";

    //Distributor table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISTIBUTOR = "CREATE TABLE " 
    + TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR + "(" + KEY_D_NO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + KEY_DNAME 
    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CITY + " TEXT, " + KEY_SALES + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_D_NO))";   


    public Helper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MAGAZINE);
        /*db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EDITOR);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_AUTHOR);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISTIBUTOR);*/
        //ins(db);
    }

    public void addMagazine(Magazine magazine) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_M_NAME, magazine.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_EDITION, magazine.getEdition()); 
        values.put(KEY_M_DATE, magazine.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_PAGES, magazine.getPages()); 
        values.put(KEY_PRICE, magazine.getPrice());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_MAGAZINE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void ins(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MAGAZINE + " VALUES('Times Now',12,030112,45,40.50)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MAGAZINE + " VALUES('Times Finance',3,220410,52,50.00)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_AUTHOR + " VALUES(007,'Ashwin M',040594,M,15)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_AUTHOR + " VALUES(002,'Shino Aburame',221296,M,4)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_AUTHOR + " VALUES(004,'Percy Shelley',210684,F,50)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_EDITOR + " VALUES(001,'Lady Tsunade',140883,F,10)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_EDITOR + " VALUES(005,'Akshay K',150980,M,2)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_EDITOR + " VALUES(101,'O Henry',181165,M,25)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ARTICLE + " VALUES(003,220414,'Endangered Insects',002,001)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ARTICLE + " VALUES(104,280390,'Ode To The West Wind',004,101)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ARTICLE + " VALUES(81,140210,'Road To Stardom',007,005)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ARTICLE + " VALUES(81,140210,'Hidden Leaf Village',002,001)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " VALUES('Lifestyle',12)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " VALUES('News',14)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " VALUES('Entertainment',21)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " VALUES('Education',4)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT + " VALUES('Washing Machine','IFB',5)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT + " VALUES('3 BHK Condo','Prestige',11)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT + " VALUES('R8 LeMans','Audi',8)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR + " VALUES(11,'Advaith','Bangalore',40)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR + " VALUES(05,'Kakashi','Tokyo',85)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR + " VALUES(03,'Penguin','New York',120)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        //on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MAGAZINE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ARTICLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EDITOR);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AUTHOR);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DISTRIBUTOR);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ADVERTISEMENT);

        //create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: a small advice, put your queries in a raw text file and read them into a string array. It's easier to manage on and off android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the variable names holding your column names out of the string literals in the `PRIMARY KEY` declaration.

Change this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MAGAZINE = "CREATE TABLE " 
+ TABLE_MAGAZINE + "(" + KEY_M_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_EDITION 
+ " INTEGER, " + KEY_M_DATE + " INTEGER," + KEY_PAGES + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " 
+ KEY_PRICE + " REAL, PRIMARY KEY(KEY_M_NAME, KEY_M_DATE))";
```

to

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MAGAZINE = "CREATE TABLE " 
+ TABLE_MAGAZINE + "(" + KEY_M_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_EDITION 
+ " INTEGER, " + KEY_M_DATE + " INTEGER," + KEY_PAGES + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " 
+ KEY_PRICE + " REAL, PRIMARY KEY(" + KEY_M_NAME + "," +  KEY_M_DATE + "))";
```

There are similar problems in your other tables, too, though the code that runs the SQL has been commented out for now.